# Conditional Statement for Random Number Generator in a range (in c)

Tags: c, conditional-statements

What i am trying to accomplish is that:

User has 3 tries.

Please guess the number.(wrong)

You guessed wrong.

Your number is too (high or low).

You have 2 tr(ies) left.
(user guesses wrong)

You guessed wrong.

Your number is too (high or low).

You have 1 tr(y) left.

As above. I'm trying to change the letters after "tr" if the user has left more
 than 1 its "ies" and "y" for one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int num, guess, tries = 0;
    srand(time(0)); /* seed random number generator */
    num = rand() % 20 + 0; /* random number between 1 and 100 */
    int max_guess=3;
    printf("Guess My Number Game\n\n");

    do
    {
        printf("Enter a guess between 0 and 20 : ");
        scanf("%d", &guess);
        tries++;

        if (guess > num)
        {
            printf("Too high!");
            printf("You have %d tries left.\n\n",max_guess--);
        }
        else if (guess < num)
        {
            printf("Too low!");
            printf("You have %d tr%c left.\n\n",max_guess--,(tries=1 ? y));
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nCorrect! You got it in %d guesses!\n", tries);
        }

    }
      while (guess != num);

    return 0;
}
```

What can i do to increase the readability for the conditional statements in printf.

Comment: A possible solution is to add a function that takes the number, the tries, and whether it was high or low, and then prints out the solution. If the number of tries left is 1, print 'try'; else print 'tries'. You could also likely inline this with the ternary operator - I'll have a look at it.

Comment: `printf("...tr%s...", max_guess>1 ? "ies" : "y")`

Comment: @pmg  Suggest `max_guess != 1` because if `max_guess` were zero, you'd want `0 tries left` not `0 try left` .. Actually I'd swap the strings and have `max_guess == 1` but that is a matter of style rather then substance - it is just a more attractive operator ;-)  .  You might of course want `no tries left` substituting `no` for zero, but that is a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a ternary operator inside of your print function to selectively print "tries" or "try" based on how many tries are left.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int tries = 3;
  for(int tries = 3; tries >= 0; tries--) {
    printf("%d %s left.\n", tries, 
      tries != 1 ? "tries" : "try"
    );
  }
  return 0;
}
```

> 3 tries left.
>   2 tries left.
>   1 try left.
>   0 tries left.

`tries != 1 ? "tries" : "try"` means "if (`?`) tries != 1, return the string "tries", else (`:`) return the string "try".

Comment: Why `fprintf(stdout...` rather than `printf(...`, if _readability_ is he aim?  Also for readability I'd suggest: `printf( "%d %s left.\n", tries, tries == 1 ? "try" : "tries" ) ;`.  The splitting of the word saves little and costs a lot in readability.  The extra parentheses are also redundant.  If you want to have the expression "stand out", place it in a new line of its own perhaps.